# regex to catch any currency under $300K

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a requirement to identify any values under 300,000 in a currency field. I created a regex that will do this for any number under 1 million, but I need to cut it off at $299,999.99.

The code for 1 million is listed below.

`^\$?\d{0,3}?\d{0,2},?\d{0,3}(\.(\d{0,2}))?$`

Comment: why do you need regex for this? Can't you use a comparison operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:
`^\$[0-2]?[0-9]{0,2},?[0-9]{0,3}(\.[0-9]+)?$`

[See the explanation on regex101...](https://regex101.com/r/S1vK0f/2)

[image]

[Here you can visualize your regular expression...](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5C%24%5B0-2%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B0%2C2%7D%2C%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B0%2C3%7D(%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B)%3F%24)

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is not your best choice here.

To illustrate this, I will use the regex you posted for the $1 million case.  It looks to me like you are trying to accommodate various conditions, including things like:

```
$10      vs.  $10.00
$100     vs.  100
$100     vs.  $10000
$10,000  vs.  $100,000
etc.
```

But the way you are doing that allows for things like this:

```
$10000000.00
```

because:

```
$            matches  ^\$?
100          matches  \d{0,3}?
00           matches  \d{0,2}
[no comma ]  matches  ,?
000          matches  \d{0,3}
.00          matches  (\.(\d{0,2}))?$
```

(tested with with https://regex101.com/)

Said differently, your attempt to match things like the absence of a comma for small numbers and the presence of a comma for large numbers, and the various groupings of digits that might occur in small, medium and large numbers results in a regex that matches a number much greater than $1 million.

While regular expressions are quite versatile, and modern regex engines are quite powerful, a robust regex to perform what you are trying to do would be cumbersome, hard to read, and hard to maintain.

It would also be complex enough that it would show the ways in which regex can properly be considered to be a programming language.

But most of all, any regex is used within the context of a surrounding programming language, so why not just use the facilities of the programming language itself?  It might take more typing, but probably less time, and the results will be much easier to compose, read, and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, `$300,000.00 - $1,000,000.00`

`(?<!\S)\$?(3\d{2},?\d{3}|[4-9]\d{2},?\d{3}|10{6}|1,?000,?000)(\.\d{0,2})?(?!\S)`

Readable version

```
 (?<! \S )
 \$?
 (                             # (1 start)
      3 \d{2} ,? \d{3} 
   |  [4-9] \d{2} ,? \d{3} 
   |  1 0{6}
   |  1 ,? 000 ,? 000
 )                             # (1 end)
 (                             # (2 start)
      \.
      \d{0,2} 
 )?                            # (2 end)
 (?! \S )
```